# How do i inject a class with extension methods ? ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, extension-methods, asp.net-identity

I try to inject in my controller the ApplicationUserManager from ASP.NET Identity. 
This is the class i try to inject :

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationUserManager
    { ... }
```

This is how i try to inject in my controller :

```
        private readonly IApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public MyController(IApplicationUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
```

The thing is when i try to get the methods from the _userManager, when i write `_userManager.` the intellisense gives me only the Async methods . For example  `_userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync()` instead of `_userManager.RemoveFromRole()`.
This happens because my interface has only the async methods. But the **Sync** methods **(not Async)** are extension methods for UserManager.

```
public static class UserManagerExtensions
    { ...
    public static IdentityResult RemoveFromRole<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TKey userId,
                string role)
                where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
                where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
            {
                if (manager == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
                }
                return AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => manager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(userId, role));
            }
        ...}
```

UserManager also derives from another class :

```
public class UserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser, string> where TUser : class, IUser<string>
    {
     ...
     }
```

**The question is : How do I manage to get the Sync methods in my controller ???**

Answer (score 0):

As the extension methods apply to the class definition rather than the interface, you would also need to cast from and IApplicationUserManager to a UserManager first.  Unfortunately this is not great practice from the DI and mocking point of view.
To illustrate this, this should work...

```
if (IApplicationUserManager is UserManager)
{
    UserManager userManager = (UserManager)IApplicationUserManager ;
    userManager.RemoveFromRole(...)
}
```

But I am not recommending this, as the controller should not have knowledge of the implementation, and this is where your problem is.  The fact of the matter is that an extension method is by its nature defined only on the class implementation, the interface has no knowledge of it.

As such it might in fact be better to place the extension method functionality in a method that is declared on the interface.

Comment: I added the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace. It contains the UserManagerExtensions. Still doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean with " you also need to case from and IApplicationUserManager to a UserManager first " . I don't understand  what you mean with the verb "case" (I'm not a native english speaker).

Comment: Yes, that was a typo!  I meant "cast"

Answer (score 0):

DI doesn't require an interface, it requires an *abstraction*. Since your implementation is subclassed, it is valid to say your abstraction is `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. This also implies that another implementation of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` is valid.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{ ... }

private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

Now, if your controller depends on additional members of what is currently `IApplicationUserManager` (and I would expect so), you need to make those members into an abstract base class so it can be injected into your controller, so it can also inherit `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : ApplicationUserManagerBase
{ ... }

public abstract class ApplicationUserManagerBase : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{ ... }

private readonly ApplicationUserManagerBase _userManager;

public MyController(ApplicationUserManagerBase userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

To make an implementation or mock, you would just need to inherit `ApplicationUserManagerBase`. This is better than casting because the implementation is loosely coupled from the abstraction.

Oh, and back to your original problem - all of the extension methods of `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` will be available on `ApplicationUserManager` if you follow this approach. The big clue is in the extension method definition: `this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager` - you must define an abstraction that includes this abstraction for it to work.